# jasper reports ireport subreports order

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a report that contains *subreports* A, B, C, and D and ids 1 and 2.

Currently when my report runs it runs A-1, A-2, B-1, B-2, C-1, C-2, D-1, D-2.

How can I change it to display *subreports* A,B,C,D for id 1 and then A,B,C,D for id 2 etc. for each id passed in?

Comment: You can add group by id.

Comment: where do i group it? I don't have a query in the main report. Each subreport contains its query